# Cocoa / Mac OS: Get color of window toolbar

Tags: objective-c, macos, qt, window

I'm making a Qt application where I need a tab widget in the exact color as the toolbar in Mac OS.

I'm not happy about just using a color picker to sample the color, as it might change slighty according to OS version. As I'm pretty sure this can't be done in Qt itself, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to do this natively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `[NSColor windowFrameColor]` or one of the [other class methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000353-SW6) will get the color for the toolbar. you can get the RGB values from the NSColor if you need to after that. I'm not familiar with Qt, but you tagged this as obj-c so I assume this helps you.

Edit for gradients:
here is [an explanation](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Dec/msg01259.html) from an apple engineer how NSColor produces gradients.

> ```
> [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
> NSRectFill(someRect);
> ```
>
> This works because the selectedMenuItemColor is a pattern that happens to draw a gradient. You could just as easily draw nearly anything with a pattern, and Quartz treats patterns just like colors

Comment: Accepted as answer - although I gave up implementing this after I realized that the frame color is actually a gradient.

Comment: @Zumteufel I updated the answer with an explanation of how NSColor can do gradients. It may or may not help you.